# Postcode Searching

Tags: search, mapping, postal-code

Im not sure of the best way for getting what I am after so I will just explain it's application and hope a wiser person than me knows what i am in need of.

I am after something pretty much the same as on www.Autotrader.co.uk where the user enters a full postcode and a search area (radius) from that postcode (1 mile / 10 miles / 100 miles etc) and then only results within the search area are shown.

I wondering how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

search by radius... It is easier to search by applying an offset of longitude and latitude, e.g. +/- 0.00001 of the longitude and latitude. But with this approach, the search area will be in rectangle.

Google Maps API can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will describe a way to achieve your goal:
First, I would get the latitude and longitude for each user. You can use the [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). 
Add two columns for latitude and longitude in the table where you store data of the Users.
Then, you can calculate the distances between users. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) describes how you dan do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert Postcode to geographic information, then there is a lot of ways to calculate the distance between two points. So basically:

1. Using [Google's Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert postcode to longitude and latitude.
2. Calculate distance between two points. You can find some information on [UK Postcode](http://www.ukpostcode.net/calculating-distance-between-two-postcodes-with-php-wiki-9.html).

Now, if you are going to search within a database to find out how many relevant points like Autotrader. It is better to pre-cacluate all results and cache them when there is any new point coming. It will provide a faster service and minimize server's load.